# Django NameError at / name 'request' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm learning Django view at [Django Girls Tutorial](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_views/)

```
NameError at /

name 'request' is not defined

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.8
Exception Type:     NameError
Exception Value:    

name 'request' is not defined

Exception Location:     ~/DjangoStudy/blog/views.py in post_list, line 4
```

[blog/views.py](https://github.com/MuhunKim/DjangoStudy/blob/master/blog/views.py#L4)

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def post_list(requst):
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {})

# Create your views here.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your view.

It should be

```
def post_list(request):
```

instead of

```
def post_list(requst): # it should be 'request' here and not 'requst'
```